# How to Parallelize a nested for loop using CUDA to perform a computation on a 2D Array

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I am working on some research and am very much a beginner at using CUDA. The languages I'm using are C and C++, the basic languages compatible with Nvidia's CUDA. Over the past week I've been stuck on trying to get any sort of speedups through integrating CUDA with my C++ code.

As far as I know I am doing the basics correctly as far as memory allocation and deallocation is concerned. But when it comes to actually speeding up calculations, I am currently receiving different results from the non-CUDA implementation.

In addition, the CUDA implementation is also SLOWER than the normal non cuda version.

The following is the function I am calling the kernel function from. Essentially I moved the computation that was originally in this function into the kernel function in order to parallelize it.
    //compute the distance between inputs
    void computeInput(int vectorNumber, double *dist, double **weight){

```
double *d_dist, **d_weight;


//cout << "Dist[0] Before: " << dist[0] << endl;

cudaMalloc(&d_dist, maxClusters * sizeof(double));
cudaMalloc(&d_weight, maxClusters * vector_length * sizeof(double));

//  cout << "Memory Allocated" << endl;

//copy variables from host machine running on CPU to Kernel running on GPU
cudaMemcpy(d_dist, dist, maxClusters * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_weight, weight, maxClusters * vector_length * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//  cout << "Variables copied to GPU Device." << endl;

//kernel currently being run with 1 blocks with 4 threads for each block.
//right now only a single loop is parallelized, I need to parallelize each loop individually or 2d arrays individually.
dim3 blocks(8,8);
dim3 grid(1, 1);
threadedInput<<<grid,blocks>>>(vectorNumber, d_dist, d_weight);

//  cout << "Kernel Run." << endl;  

//Waits for the GPU to finish computations
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

//cout << "Weight[0][0] : " << weight[0][0];

//copy back varaible from kernelspace on GPU to host on CPU into variable weight
cudaMemcpy(weight, d_weight, maxClusters * vector_length * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(dist, d_dist, maxClusters * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
//  cout << "GPU Memory Copied back to Host" << endl;

cout << "Dist[0] After: " << dist[0] << endl;

cudaFree(d_dist);
cudaFree(d_weight);

//cout << " Cuda Memory Freed" << endl;
}
```

The following is the Kernel Function. It is calculating the distance using weights on nodes.

What I WANT it to do is to perform each iteration of the loops on separate threads.

What I fear it is doing is messing up the order and performing the wrong calculations. I have already searched through Stack Overflow and other places for help on nested for loop parallelization, yet none of them shed much light on the matter as to what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

```
__global__ void threadedInput(int vecNum, double *dist, double **weight)
{
int tests[vectors][vector_length] = {{0, 1, 1, 0},
                                     {1, 0, 0, 1},
                                     {0, 1, 0, 1},
                                     {1, 0, 1, 0}};
dist[0] = 0.0;
dist[1] = 0.0;
int indexX,indexY, incrX, incrY;
indexX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
indexY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
incrX = blockDim.x * gridDim.x; 
incrY = blockDim.y * gridDim.y; 

for(int i = indexY; i <= (maxClusters - 1); i+=incrY)
{
    for(int j = indexX; j <= (vectors - 1); j+= incrX)
    {       
        dist[i] += pow((weight[i][j] - tests[vecNum][j]), 2);
    }// end inner for
}// end outer for

}// end CUDA-kernel
```

My Current Output:

```
Clusters for training input:

Vector (1, 0, 1, 0, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (1, 1, 1, 0, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (0, 1, 1, 1, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (1, 1, 0, 0, ) Place in Bin 0

Weights for Node 0 connections:
0.74753098, 0.75753881, 0.74233157, 0.25246902, 

Weights for Node 1 connections:
0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 

Categorized test input:

Vector (0, 1, 1, 0, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (1, 0, 0, 1, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (0, 1, 0, 1, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (1, 0, 1, 0, ) Place in Bin 0
Time Ran: 0.96623900
```

Expected Output (Except that the expected time it takes should be at least 50% faster)

```
Clusters for training input:

Vector (1, 0, 1, 0, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (1, 1, 1, 0, ) Place in Bin 1

Vector (0, 1, 1, 1, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (1, 1, 0, 0, ) Place in Bin 1

Weights for Node 0 connections:
0.74620975, 0.75889148, 0.74351981, 0.25379025, 

Weights for Node 1 connections:
0.75368531, 0.75637331, 0.74105526, 0.24631469, 

Categorized test input:

Vector (0, 1, 1, 0, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (1, 0, 0, 1, ) Place in Bin 1

Vector (0, 1, 0, 1, ) Place in Bin 0

Vector (1, 0, 1, 0, ) Place in Bin 1
Time Ran: 0.00033100
```

Comment: You should look into related questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708101/parallelize-four-and-more-nested-loops-with-cuda?rq=1 for example.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your data and the calculation you intend to do with it? According to your code, you have 1 block (23/12=1) of 12x12 threads. What is `maxClusters`? What is `vectors` and `vector_length`? Where do you define them? Is the variable `tests` common to all threads? The local parameters `dist` and `weight` are they a vector and a matrix respectively? What sizes are they? It'd be better if you provide more information.

Comment: maxClusters, vector_length and vectors are all const ints. Their values are 2, 4, 4 respectively. They are defined in my full .cu file before the function declarations. tests in the form you see above is common to all threads. I have it in the kernel function because I wasn't sure if it would have access to it from where the kernel function was being called. dist and weight are both arrays where dist holds the relative distances between two points to determine the Best Matching Unit. Weight is a 2D array that holds the weights of 8 total items so a 2 x 4.

Comment: I edited my main post to contain some more relevant code and output information. For some additional important information...  

nvcc --version yields

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17

cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt on the other hand yields

CUDA Version 8.0.61

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CUDA-transfer 2D array from host to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373929/cuda-transfer-2d-array-from-host-to-device)

Comment: They are similar, but I believe the difference is that weight 2d array in mind is a 2 x 4 and the 2d array in that example is N x N which means mine is a rectangle and his is a square. Doesn't that mess with the arr[j + i * N] calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You should read some tutorials, begin with : https://devblogs.nvidia.com/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c/

Basically each thread executes the kernel code, so there should be no loop inside.

I am quoting :

> Device Code
>
> We now move on to the kernel code.

```
__global__
void saxpy(int n, float a, float *x, float *y)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < n) y[i] = a*x[i] + y[i];
}
```

> In CUDA, we define kernels such as saxpy using the **global** declaration >specifier. Variables defined within device code do not need to be specified >as device variables because they are assumed to reside on the device. In >this case the n, a and i variables will be stored by each thread in a >register, and the pointers x and y must be pointers to the device memory >address space. This is indeed true because we passed d_x and d_y to the >kernel when we launched it from the host code. The first two arguments, n >and a, however, were not explicitly transferred to the device in host code. >Because function arguments are passed by value by default in C/C++, the >CUDA runtime can automatically handle the transfer of these values to the >device. This feature of the CUDA Runtime API makes launching kernels on the >GPU very natural and easy—it is almost the same as calling a C function.
>
> There are only two lines in our saxpy kernel. As mentioned earlier, the >kernel is executed by multiple threads in parallel. If we want each thread >to process an element of the resultant array, then we need a means of >distinguishing and identifying each thread. CUDA defines the variables >blockDim, blockIdx, and threadIdx. These predefined variables are of type >dim3, analogous to the execution configuration parameters in host code. The >predefined variable blockDim contains the dimensions of each thread block >as specified in the second execution configuration parameter for the kernel >launch. The predefined variables threadIdx and blockIdx contain the index >of the thread within its thread block and the thread block within the grid, >respectively. The expression:

```
int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x
```

> generates a global index that is used to access elements of the arrays. We >didn’t use it in this example, but there is also gridDim which contains the >dimensions of the grid as specified in the first execution configuration >parameter to the launch.
>
> Before this index is used to access array elements, its value is checked >against the number of elements, n, to ensure there are no out-of-bounds >memory accesses. This check is required for cases where the number of >elements in an array is not evenly divisible by the thread block size, and >as a result the number of threads launched by the kernel is larger than the >array size. The second line of the kernel performs the element-wise work of >the SAXPY, and other than the bounds check, it is identical to the inner >loop of a host implementation of SAXPY.

```
if (i < n) y[i] = a*x[i] + y[i];
```

Comment: I have already looked at that tutorial and in fact, that tutorial is where I learned how to do proper memory allocation and de allocation when it comes to cuda memory. The problem with it however, is that it is directly incorporating the threads and blocks with its calculation intentionally. Mine on the other hand has limits defined by the dimensions of a 2d array it needs data from to perform its calculation. I am trying to parallelize each of these iterations and am not incorporating the parallelization with the answer itself.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. Can you write down a pseudo code of your program explaining wwhat you want to parallelize ?

Comment: I have just updated my main post with the function that called the kernel function and the output I am getting versus the output I should be getting.

Comment: I am sorry but you really should write the pseudo code of what you want. Because with CUDA code it is not easy to see the greater picture. I think that you have not understood how parallelism works inside CUDA kernel. And the only way to explain it on your example is to see the pseudo code, even sequential, of what you want to achieve.